# Add Event to fullcalendar scheduler using a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

In fullcalendar I've found a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/azmjv/16/) which has been able to add an event to the calendar using a bootstrap modal. I have been able to update some of the code through research to bring it up to the latest version of fullcalendar. However I am still unable to get the event to show correctly in the scheduler when i click submit. I have very little JavaScript experience and only need to get this part working for my final year project so your help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I have looked at other articles such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720577/renderevent-with-fullcalendar-scheduler-not-rendering-new-event) as well as many others including the documentation on the fullcalendar website with no luck of finding a solution. I have made a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Leventarsenal/ujdwox3m/3/) to make it easier for people to play around with the code and to find an optimal solution.

This is where I believe the issue is

```
select: function (start, end, event, view, resource) {
        endtime = end.format('h:mm a');
        starttime = start.format('ddd, MMM D, h:mm a');
        var resourceId = resource.id;
        var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
        $('#createShiftModal #employeeName').val(resourceId);
        $('#createShiftModal #shiftStartTime').val(start);
        $('#createShiftModal #shiftEndTime').val(end);
        $('#createShiftModal #when').text(mywhen);
        $('#createShiftModal').modal('show');
    }
});

$('#submitButton').on('click', function(e){
    // We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
    e.preventDefault();

    doSubmit();
  });

  function doSubmit(){
    $("#createShiftModal").modal('hide');
    console.log($('#shiftStartTime').val());
    console.log($('#shiftEndTime').val());
    alert("form submitted");

    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent',
        {
            title: $('#employeeName').val(),
            resource: $('#employeeName').val(),
            start: new Date($('#shiftStartTime').val()),
            end: new Date($('#shiftEndTime').val()),
        },
        true);
   }
```

I have struggled to implement this feature for a few months and have been unable to find any solutions online so I think a comprehensive answer and example would benefit many people in the community. Thank you for your help in advance.

**EDIT:**

To clarify the question, what I am looking for is to be able to add an event to the scheduler using a modal. When I highlight the given time range e.g 8:00am to 3:00pm I want an event to appear where I've highlighted for the given resource. For some reason the jsfiddle won't work even though the code is identical so I've launched my app on [heroku](https://mighty-thicket-99270.herokuapp.com/) so you can see what I need to be done. I just want the modal to appear with the employees name and what time and date the shift will be as a way to confirm the shift or they can click cancel to undo it.

I just need an event to appear on the calendar next to the given resource that's it. Hope this clears things up

*Login credentials*

Email: leventarsenal@gmail.com

Password: 12345

Comment: It's a bit unclear: what's the issue? What should happen that is not happening?

Comment: The most obvious problem is that `resource` should be `resourceId` in your event object - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-and-events . If you don't associate an event with a resource it won't show up on a resource-enabled view such as the timeline

Comment: If there's anything else wrong, it's hard to tell because your JSFiddle doesn't work (errors about lack of modal functionality and missing scripts) so we can't test. The other thing to check is that what's being entered for the start and end times. In your JSFiddle example the fields for shiftStartTime and shiftEndTime don't even exist.

Comment: Did the edit help clarify the issue?